# Problem design a reverse polarity protection circuit

Tags: reverse-polarity

I´m trying to develop a circuit that is able to control a starter motor with mosfets and also send a signal to control an external relay. I was able to control the starter motor through the help of a array of n channel mosfets connected in paralel. But since there is a huge amount of power necessary to control this motor I can't use the tradicional configuration of conecting a P channel mosfet for reverse polarity protection as shown in the imagem below, because it would be extremely expensive.

[image: My circuit with typical configuration of a P channel mosfet working as a reverse polarity protection]

What I managed to do is ilustrated in the circuit below, I added a P channel mosfet after the flyback diode so the current of the starter motor will not flow trough it and I was able to protect the mcu and other components that are not shown in this simplified diagram.

[image: My circuit with a kind of reverse polarity protection]

But I would like to add this protection to the whole circuit and I'm not quite sure on how to do it, keeping a small footprint and been as cheap as possible. Any ideias?

Answer (score 2):

First, you show PNP transistors being switched by +5 V from an MCU, not only will this not work, the base-emitter junction of the top transistor would put +14 V onto the MCU output through the 1K resistor which may not be good for the MCU.

Second, you are showing one relay already, and another answer is suggesting a second one. At that point why not use a solenoid instead of the MOSFETs, which is how they've been switching starter motors for about as long as they've been using starter motors?

If you use a solenoid, the motor will be disconnected until the solenoid is activated, so if you protect the rest of the circuit from reverse polarity the motor will also be protected as it will never be connected unless the rest of the circuit is working.

Comment: you are correct, I tried to make a fast simplified version of my circuit and didn't pay attention to it.
Also I'm aware of the solenoid inside starters motors, the ideia of the circuit is to isolate the chassis ground of a car from the battery ground, by doing that the current of the motor and it's solenoid will flow trough the mosfets.
I'm trying to not use moving parts for the circuit to increase reliability. The relay shown in the diagram, like I said, is external and I can't control that in the design.
With it wasn't that, that would be a ideal solution.

Comment: @RafaelMattei Starter solenoids are pretty reliable, they usually last the life of the car.
Also I don't see how MOSFETs would isolate the battery from the chassis any better than than a solenoid. Your biggest problem there is going to be that most starter motors are grounded through their frames so you'd have to isolate the whole starter.

Answer (score 1):

How about a relay?  They are cheap, handle high current, and can be turned on in only one direction when a series diode is added.  See below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhgesK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>